# Webjob giving an outofmemoryexception

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

My webjob does very little, it downloads about 3kb of data then updates some information in my database.  However after the webjob starts up and whilst it is downloading the information (or just after) an exception is thrown

```
[07/27/2014 00:12:47 > b2b30d: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException.
```

Any ideas why this would be the case?

I have run the exe locally with exactly the same data and it uses minimal memory, I've seen a maximum of 65mb but I don't think this is enough to cause an exception (or is there a limit on webjobs?)

My memory usage statistic (on the Azure dashboard) says 54% of 512 MB / hour (seems like I'm using a lot but there's still a lot available).
File System Storage 9% of 1024 MB
I'm using a Shared Hosting Plan Mode.

The database is not hit before it throws the exception so this is not a database issue.

**Update - Diagnostic information on Azure using System.Diagnostic**

```
[07/28/2014 09:07:19 > b2b30d: INFO] WorkingSet64:10.54297
[07/28/2014 09:07:19 > b2b30d: INFO] TotalPhysicalMemory:14335.55
[07/28/2014 09:07:19 > b2b30d: INFO] AvailablePhysicalMemory:8458.691
[07/28/2014 09:07:20 > b2b30d: INFO] OutOfMemoryException
[07/28/2014 09:07:20 > b2b30d: INFO] WorkingSet64:41.33594
[07/28/2014 09:07:20 > b2b30d: INFO] TotalPhysicalMemory:14335.55
[07/28/2014 09:07:21 > b2b30d: INFO] AvailablePhysicalMemory:8443.027
```

So, my program starts and is using 10mb, does some work, then throws an outofmemoryexception, at the point where outofmemoryexception is thrown the memory has increased to 41mb.  I would not have thought that an exe using 41mb is too much for a webjob to handle, why is this occuring?

Comment: Starting and stopping the website temporarily fixes things but it runs out of memory after a while.

Comment: So I've just added some diagnostic information, I'll see what that show's up.

Comment: The only person who can answer your question is yourself. Run a memory profiler on a similar data-set and see what eats the most of your memory. I'm pretty sure the fault is not with Azure platform.

Comment: So, on the server, the WorkingSet64 is 10mb, the TotalPhysicalMemory:14,335mb and the AvailablePhysicalMemory:7,866mb

Comment: When I run it on my machine at the point on the server that it fails the TotalPhysicalMemory increases to 54mb but it continues.

Comment: So, there IS enough memory on Azure's server but when run on Azure's server my throws the OutOfMemoryException hence why I think that it is a problem on Azure's server (I had mentioned in my question that it was running ok on my machine pointing to the live db but I will update my question now)

Comment: Is this a dedicated site or free?

Comment: It is on a Shared website plan

Comment: Can you share the exception's stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog seems to suggest that

'While you can experiment with continuous jobs in free or shared websites, it'll only work properly in a standard website that has the "always on" setting set, this is since in free/shared sites the jobs process will be brought down after about 20 minutes of no requests to it (a request to the jobs process can be to check the status of current jobs).'

http://blog.amitapple.com/post/73574681678/git-deploy-console-app/#.VA7TEmcXJ3V

Answer (score 1):

Modify the Batch Size property as follows

```
    JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
//This asserts that the number of parallel calls of the function is one
     config.Queues.BatchSize = 1;
     var host = new JobHost(config);
// The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
     host.RunAndBlock();
```

By doing this, each instance of your webjob calls the main function once at a time rather than parallel calls.
Good luck!